# Returning unmodified argument efficiently

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function which should either modify an instance of an object or return it unmodified, which can be simplified into this code:

```
struct MyObject
{
    bool ShouldNotChange;
    int SomeData[10];
};

void ModifyObject_inplace(MyObject & object)
{
    if (object.ShouldNotChange) return;

    // Modify object here
    object.SomeData[1] = 1;
}
```

For a number of reasons I'd like to convert this code into a more functional style:

```
MyObject ModifyObject(MyObject object)
{
    if (object.ShouldNotChange)
        return object;

    object.SomeData[1] = 1;
    return object;
}
```

The problem is that this function is performance critical and when modified in such a way it becomes slower.
I tried several different variants.

```
MyObject ModifyObject_constref(const MyObject & object)
{
    if (object.ShouldNotChange)
        return object;

    auto result = object;
    result.SomeData[1] = 1;
    return result;
}

std::shared_ptr<MyObject> ModifyObject_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<MyObject> & object_ptr)
{
    if (object_ptr->ShouldNotChange)
        return object_ptr;

    object_ptr->SomeData[1] = 1;
    return object_ptr;
}


MyObject && ModifyObject_rvalue(MyObject object)
{
    if (object.ShouldNotChange)
        return std::move(object);

    MyObject newRoute = object;
    newRoute.SomeData[1] = 1;
    return std::move(newRoute);
}
```

But only the `ModifyObject_inplace` gives the fastest code (judging by disassembly). In fact only `ModifyObject_inplace` was translated by the compiler into a function without a single jump in assembly code.
I'm using VC++ 2017.

Is there any way that I can implement it in functional style without performance hit?

Comment: `ModifyObject_inpace` is operating in a local copy of the object which is not retutned and thus the whole function call will be optimized away...

Comment: What do you mean by *"functional style"* ? (return value, const argument, ...) ?

Comment: @florestan No, that was just a type, sorry. I have already updated the question. 'ModifyObject_inpace' is the fastest when it takes a reference.

Comment: It is the fastest becaus all other methods make some sort of copy

Comment: @Jarod42 Necessarily, return value. Ideally, const argument

Comment: Why do you need to return by value?

Answer (score 2):

You can have:

```
MyObject& ModifyObject(MyObject& object)
{
    if (object.ShouldNotChange) return object;

    // Modify object here
    object.SomeData[1] = 1;
    return object;
}
```

If you require const argument, then some copy will be required, which will be more expensive than in place modification + return by reference.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about it. But even without `const` it is still not as good as the inplace version. At least in VC++2017.

Comment: @Max don't draw conclusions only from assembly. Profile! and see

Answer (score 1):

## Analyzing your attempts

```
MyObject ModifyObject(MyObject object)
```

This will involve at least a copy of the object. Not ideal when you can avoid this.

```
MyObject ModifyObject_constref(const MyObject & object)
```

Again you will need to copy the parameter into the return object. The same problem.

```
std::shared_ptr<MyObject> ModifyObject_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<MyObject> & object_ptr)
```

No, no, no, no... No! `shared_ptr` is used to manage resource lifetime when multiple objects with different lifetimes are owners of a resource. That is it's usage. Period. If you don't have this situation don't use `shared_ptr`. Moreover `shared_ptr` has a very significant impact on performance. There are at least an external shared state and 2 indirections associated with `shared_ptr`.

```
MyObject && ModifyObject_rvalue(MyObject object)
   // ...
   return std::move(object);
```

Undefined behavior! You return a reference to an argument of the function. `object` ends it's lifetime when the function ends you end up with a reference to a dead object. Also in your case moving is equivalent with copying. There is no resource in `MyObject` that can be stolen in a move so the move actually performs a copy.

## A solution

As `Jarod42` showed you

```
MyObject& ModifyObject(MyObject& object)
```

Is the fastest one because you just pass references around. No new objects created, no copying done.

> Necessarily, return value. Ideally, const argument

If you have a const argument and you need to return a modified object then you most definitely need to create a new object and this involves a copy. If this is your requirement then I would go with:

```
MyObject ModifyObject_1(MyObject object)
{
    if (!object.ShouldNotChange)
        object.SomeData[1] = 1;

    return object;
}
```

or

```
MyObject ModifyObject_2(const MyObject& object)
{
    MyObject r{object};

    if (!r.ShouldNotChange)
        r.SomeData[1] = 1;

    return r;
}
```

or

```
MyObject ModifyObject_3(const MyObject& object)
{

    if (object.ShouldNotChange)
        return object;

    MyObject r{object};
    r.SomeData[1] = 1;

    return r;
}
```

Which one of these is the fastest? Well you need to **profile** which you should do anyway. Don't draw conclusions from assembly, unless they are backed up by profiling. For performance critical code **profile, profile, profile**!

## Functional programming and performance

In *pure* functional code (which is what you seem to want) all object are immutable. This implies a copy whenever you need to modify an object. This has an impact on performance. You need to decide if the tradeoff is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to add a method to MyObject?
It looks that you do not need a function that returns different objects but rather a method that either modify the object or not.
Method could also return this or reference to the object if needed.
Might be good to suggest compiler to inline.